# Entity Framework 4 - update/insert views

Tags: entity-framework-4, view

My EF schema has a mixture of tables and views from my database. My view entities are all read-only, I want to be able to update/insert into these entities. I've tried the following post without any luck:

http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/entity-framework-creating-a-model-using-views-instead-of-tables/

Anyone have another ideas/pointers - this must be doable.

cheers
David

Answer (score 3):

Generally the post is correct. Using views in EF is hard. Another trick is first using tables to define your model and then replace tables in database with views with same names as tables.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried Instead of Triggers?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236425/How-to-insert-data-using-SQL-Views-created-using-m